# Runtime error 438 when copying from one workbook to the other

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, runtime-error

I'm running this code to copy data from one workbook into another main workbook but keep getting runtime error 438 at line 12. Whats going on? Thanks in advance!

```
 1     Sub copydata()
 2     Dim wbk As Workbook
 3     Dim wbk2 As Workbook
 4     strFirstFile = Userform1.path.Text
 5     Set wbk2 = ThisWorkbook
 6     Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)
 7     With wbk.Sheets(1)
 8      Cells(1, 1).Activate
 9         ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
10         Selection.Copy
11     End With
12     wbk2.Sheets("UAL").Range("G1").Paste
13     Application.CutCopyMode = False
14     wbk.Close
15     
16     End Sub
```

Comment: The lack of dots in the With block cause the contained code to relate to the current workbook, not wbk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range` doesn't support method `Paste`. Use this pattern:

```
Selection.Copy Destination:=wbk2.Sheets("UAL").Range("G1")
```

or you can use `PasteSpecial`:

```
wbk2.Sheets("UAL").Range("G1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

BTW, avoid using `Select` statement. You can use this one instead lines 7-12 (which are not correct in your code, since you've missed period `.` before `Cells(1, 1)` and etc):

```
With wbk.Sheets(1)
     .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=wbk2.Sheets("UAL").Range("G1")
End With
```

Comment: the first one got rid of the error but didn't perform the action but the second one and third ones worked. Thanks! I went with the third one because it was simpler and didn't use select.

Comment: @SRoy, when you're using `With` statement, you should also use `.` before all objects inside `with` statement, that're related to `wbk.Sheets(1)` (in your case). Period will help VBA to understand that `Cells` belongs to `wbk.Sheets(1)`. There is more examples of using `With` statement [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)